# C# Mysql cultureinfo.invariantculture

Tags: c#, mysql, cultureinfo

I have an double value in my insert request. I change the comma into a dot in this double value and have 12.5 instead of 12,5 when I create my MySqlCommand like in MySQL rules. But my string change my dot into a comma and send insert request with a comma and fired an exception. Why does MySqlCommand create a string with 12,5 and not 12.5?

```
string valueCapteur = "12,5";
valueCapteur = valueCapteur.Replace(',', '.');
double.TryParse(valueCapteur, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out double value);
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand
{
    Connection = cnn,
    CommandText = "INSERT INTO `notification`(`Value`) VALUES (" + value + ");"
};
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

When I debug value = 12.5 but in my cmd.CommandText value = 12,5

Comment: Use parameters instead of string concatenation. Also, don't confuse what is displayed as string in the debugger with the actual value.

Comment: The only reason you'll have a problem with `,` is if you store numbers as *strings* instead of using the correct type. Either your field's type is `varchar` or your *actual* code uses string concatenation.

Comment: but... but... you don't *use* `value` in the SQL... there are no parameters, no concatenation, and no interpolated literals... your SQL *doesn't touch* `value` *at all*... is the real code `CommandText = "INSERT INTO \`notification\`(\`Value\`) VALUES ({value});"` ?

Comment: my mistake value is use in concat string like this "... VALUES (" + value + ");
I will try with params and edit my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want are *parameters*:

```
using(MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand {
    Connection = cnn,
    CommandText = "INSERT INTO `notification`(`Value`) VALUES (@value);"
})
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", value);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

or with a tool like "Dapper":

```
conn.Execute("INSERT INTO `notification`(`Value`) VALUES (@value);", new { value });
```

One of the key points of parameters - in addition to avoiding SQL Injection - is that it avoids culture and formatting issues.